# Get current page number in InDesign CS5 from Javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, flash-cs5

What is the DOM expression to get current page where the cursor is:

```
app.activeDocument.currentPage ?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want:

```
app.activeWindow.activePage.name;
```

This will give you the actual page number name as a string (i.e. if your pages are numbered in roman then this will give 'v' for the fifth page).

Comment: Is there a way to find out page number from a textFrame?

Comment: Is it possible to get the index of the page and not the name ?

Answer (score 0):

The below would create a Text Block with the current page number. You could also have this be applied to the master page by changing the page location for which the text frame is placed.

```
myDocument = app.activeDocument;
var myDocument = app.documents.item(0);
var myPage = myDocument.pages.item(0);
var myTextFrame = myPage.textFrames.add();
//Set the bounds of the text frame.
//
myTextFrame.geometricBounds = [0, 0, .52, 5.5];
//Enter text in the text frame.
//("\r" is a return character.+
myTextFrame.contents = "P_";
myTextFrame.parentStory.insertionPoints.item(-1).contents = SpecialCharacters.autoPageNumber;
```

Comment: Is there a way to find out page number from a textFrame?